# exactly once from a set of characters perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl

how to check exactly one character from a group of characters in perl using regexp.Suppose from (abcde) i want to check if out of all these 5 characters only one has occured which can occur multiple times.I have tried quantifiers but it does not work for a set of characters.

Comment: You have to be more clear. Are you looking 1 character in the set, occurring multiple times, while at the same time the others should _not_ exist multiple times ?

Comment: I am looking that only one of the character should occur out of these 5 characters and that one character can repeat. "ghijkaa" should be matched where as "ghijkaab" should not be matched

Comment: Then the general solution you seek is `^[^a-e]*([a-e])(?:\1|[^a-e])*\z` which is ikegami's second regex

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex match:

```
/
   ^
   [^a-e]*+
   (?: a [^bcde]*+
   |   b [^acde]*+
   |   c [^abde]*+
   |   d [^abce]*+
   |   e [^abcd]*+
   )
   \z
/x
```

The following is a simpler pattern that might be less efficient:

```
/ ^ [^a-e]*+ ([a-e]) (?: \1|[^a-e] )*+ \z /x
```

A non-regex solution might be simpler.

```
# Count the number of instances of each letter.
my %chars;
++$chars{$_} for split //;

# Count how many of [a-e] are found.
my $count = 0;
++$count for grep $chars{$_}, qw( a b c d e );

$count == 1
```

Comment: What are `*+` and `++`?

Comment: They are like `*` and `+`, but they won't match less than the max. E.g., `/^a++a/` can't possibly match. In my answer,  they are purely being used as an optimisation to speed up backtracking, so they can safely be replaced with `*` and `+`

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to return a list of matches. then you can store the result in an array.

```
my @arr = "abcdeaa" =~ /a/g; print scalar @arr ."\n";
```

prints 3

```
 my @arr = "bcde" =~ /a/g; print scalar @arr ."\n";
```

prints 0

if you use scalar @arr. it will return the length of the array.

Comment: How does this tell us that `availing` matches and `avocado` doesn't?

Comment: I was a little unsure about exactly what the question was getting at. And i could see the questioner getting down votes. So i thought i put the questioner on the right track and they can comment if they're still lost.....